# JBoss modules cxf jar updating?

Tags: cxf, jboss-eap-6, jboss-modules

I'm using JBOSS EAP 6.2 for deploying the restful web service. The restful web service is using apache cxf, it is taking from jboss eap. Currently its using the jar cxf-api-2.7.7.redhat-1.jar . Is there any way that can I update this jar in the jboss modules also modules.xml.

Comment: I am also looking for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded jars on the server in the past by replacing the .jar file and updating the module.xml file with the new jar file name. Though not CXF (Make sure you stop the server first)

cxf is in %JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\cxf